# How to unit test API calls with axios() in react-native with Jest

Tags: react-native, redux, jestjs

I am developing Sample Application in React-native . I used Jest to use unit testing, i don't have an idea about Jest Api call 
I want to need without using Promises:
Here this is my Code:

this is My Function Code:

```js
/**
 * @description Action to call nilpick service ,on success increment route as well as mark the location as fulfilled
 */

function nilPick() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const currentState = getState();
    const { user, picking } = currentState;
    const { currentRouteIndex, pickRoute } = getState().picking.pickRouteInfo;
    const { workId } = picking.pickWorkInfo;
    const nilPickItem = pickRoute[currentRouteIndex];
    const currentItem = getCurrentItem(currentState);
    const currentTime = dateFunctions.getCurrentUTC();

    const nilpickedItem = [
      {
        orderId: nilPickItem.fulfillOrdNbr,
        lineNbr: nilPickItem.ordLine,
        pickUpcNbr: nilPickItem.upc,
        pickDisplayTs: currentTime,
        pickUom: currentItem.workDetail.uom,
        pickedLoc: nilPickItem.location,
        locationType: nilPickItem.locType,
        locId: nilPickItem.locId,
        pickByType: currentItem.workDetail.pickByType,
        exceptionPick: false,
        gtinPrefRankNbr: 0,
        pickUpcTypeCd: 5100
      }
    ];

    const { status, statusText } = await pickingService.nilPick(nilpickedItem, user, workId);
    if (status === 200 || statusText === 'Created') {
      console.info('Item nilpicked');
      if (currentRouteIndex < pickRoute.length) {
        dispatch(incrementRoute());
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          'Nilpick Complete',
          [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              onPress: () => {
                dispatch(endPicking());
              }
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
        console.log('End of pickwalk');
        return;
      }
    } else {
      console.info('error in nilpicking item ');
    }
  };
}
```

This is my code above method to Converting Like this below sample test Case:
    This is sample Test  i want to call Api How to implement in Jest

```js
it('Test For nillPic', () => {
  const initialState = {
    picking: {
      pickRouteInfo: {
        "fulfillOrdNbr": pickRouteInfo.fulfillOrdNbr,
        "orderLine": '1',
        "upc": '4155405089',
        "location": 'A-1-1',
        "availableLocsToPick": '2',
        'suggSubPendingPicks?': 'N',
        'manualSubPendingPicks?': 'N',
        "lineFullfilled": 'false',
        "currentRouteIndex": 1,
        "pickRoute": ['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
      }
    }
  };
  // console.log("state data...", initialState);
  const store = mockStore(initialState);
  store.dispatch(actions.pickRouteActions.nilPickSuccess());
  const expectedAction = [{ type: 'INCREMENT_ROUTE' }];
  const localActions = store.getActions();
  expect(localActions).toEqual(expectedAction);
});
```

Finally This is my code Please . Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am not very clear what do you ask?

Comment: to test api axios  methods checking using jest test cases